# SSRS Parameters - Display Month name and Year in the list instead of a Calendar

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have two date parameters in my report
@FirstDate
@LastDate

Currently, I have the default Calendar view and I want the parameters to display the Month Name (Jan-Dec) and Year(2000-2050) value lists instead.

Clicking on calendar icon of the parameter field should display a list that would look like below with present month and year highlighted/selected by default-

Month(name) | Year(value)

I want to know if this can be achieved in Reporting services and if yes how to do it. Really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What source are you using for the report? If it's SQL Server or Oracle, I'd recommend creating a calendar table. Then you could query it how ever you need.

Comment: Do you mean you want 4 parameters in total or just two lists each with 1320  entries in?

Comment: The year (1990-2099) was just for reference, I’d probably just use (2000-2050) or a lesser range. I actually want one parameter field (say Month) which when clicked on would display a list with Month names on the LHS and Year values on the RHS with current month and year highlighted by default and the ability to select any month and year value with the help of navigation keys (or anything similar).

Comment: @aduguid I have a Calendar table added as a second dataset in my report now, could you please elaborate on how I can use it to display month and year values only in the parameter fields? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of months over a period (2000 - 2050), you would need to create a Dataset with the months and use that dataset as the Available Values of the parameter.

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = '01/01/2000' 
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = '12/01/2050'

;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT THEDATE, 
        UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, THEDATE) AS CHAR(3))) + ' ' 
            + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, THEDATE) AS CHAR(4)) TEXT_DATE
FROM GETDATES 
ORDER BY THEDATE
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

The parameter would use TEXT_DATE as the label and THEDATE as the value.

For the default value, you'd just need to get the first day of the current month to match the corresponding THEDATE value field for the current month.

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day)
```